# How to detect Restfull APIs are getting called in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley, retrofit, httpclient

I am working on a library in which i need to identify when API gets called and finish. Ex Need to check login, logout, userdetails etc API calling.
Library should auto detect API calling. Irrespective of network library is use for API calling..(Retrofit, Volley, HTTPClient..etc).

Is there any event available to detect API calling.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you are looking for this library -> [okhttp logging interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor), which, once properly installed will print in `Logcat` everything related to your network communication: sent requests, detect API calls, timeouts, errors etc. It integrates well with `Retrofit`, and probably other libraries you mentioned.

Also, you may want to try a built-in tool in Android Studio -> **Network Profiler** (Network tab in Android Profiler). There, you can also detect API calls and networking in a more visual way of delivery (graphs and tables)